# BSD namespace existence

Tags: namespace, bsd

Does BSD (Free/Net/Open etc.) have namespace implementation in their kernel (like in Linux). Because I did not find any clear explanation on internet.

Comment: Have a look at FreeBSD jail, not the same, but for the same purpose.

Comment: I'm fully aware of those things but that's not what I meant . Because Jails are basically chroot wrapper which does not provide any good isolation. Instead I mean the actual namespace implementation in the kernel level.